# Hardware pause button doesn't work for Chrome media

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, touch-bar

Similar to (but opposite of) [Pause button started working for Chrome / Youtube, messing with audio player controls](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360604), I can't get the touch bar Play/Pause button to play or pause Youtube videos in Chrome.

I checked that chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling was enabled.

When I manually play or pause the video in the browser it changes the touch bar icon between playing and paused, but tapping the icon doesn't do anything.

How can I get the media key to control Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2477469?hl=en&msgid=23986136

If you have the Google Play Music extension installed, uninstall it. The touch bar play pause button works correctly after that.

Comment: Same with StreamKeys chrome extension, Uninstalling it did the trick!